# Does app store show a limited impressions for every account?

Tags: ios-appstore, apple-id, app-store-connect, developer-program

Does apple have something like a quota "limited views monthly" for every developer account? Do I need to have another account to get more reach through impressions and installs??

1- I used to to get about 150-200k impressions in the first 1-2 days for every new app I publish in the old days = means more installs too but this is no longer happens.

2- I don't see any much difference on my profits I know this: from my Admob ads analytics/daily impressions almost the same range every day.

> I'm looking forward to understand the changes so I can improve my
>   efforts and ROI. Is it legal to have more than account on app store?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does apple have something like a quota "limited views monthly" for every developer account?

No.

> I used to to get about 150-200k impressions in the first 1-2 days for every new app I publish in the old days = means more installs too but this is no longer happens.

These impressions were probably from users browsing the App Store's list of newly added apps. The App Store no longer surfaces any such list; you will need to find other ways to bring your app to users' attention.

(There are some lists of "New Apps We Love" and "Best New Updates", but these lists are manually curated -- not all new or updated apps will show up on them.)

> Is it legal to have more than account on app store?

I'm not aware of any specific rules against it, but it won't do you any good here.

Answer (score 1):

That's the reply from app store support on this question:

> One developer account would suffice to get the same results for your
>   apps as different accounts. You may avail of this